# convert string in integer all the time with power automate

Tags: office365, power-automate

I'm parsing a table out from a mail with power automate. I just need to get the last item of the table. I managed to get this specific row and manage do store it into a variable.

But i failed to convert it to integer.

My data can takes several forms like : 480 000 or just 0 or -0,03 or 452 000,23.

All i want is to convert the string into integer in order to make some logical test with the data after.

Best regards,

Kair0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use expression function `int(yourstringproperty)` to convert a string value to an integer.

When your numeric representation is formatted, you may need to do some extra conversion:

`int(replace(replace(yourstringproperty, " ", ""), ",", "."))`

Comment: It's not working for 480 000 or -125 or -0,25 or 125 123,23

Comment: I extended my answer. Does it work for you?